# Create a postgres docker-compose with a local mount volume

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, ownership

I have the follow code of my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

But when I do  `docker compose up`, the console give me the next error:

```
servicios-basesdatos-db-1 exited with code 1
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | This user must also own the server process.
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | 
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | 
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | Data page checksums are disabled.
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | 
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | creating subdirectories ... ok
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | selecting default max_connections ... 20
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | creating configuration files ... ok
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | 2023-01-31 09:07:54.976 UTC [83] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | 2023-01-31 09:07:54.976 UTC [83] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | child process exited with exit code 1
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

And I can't up my docker.

How can I fix it so that it works?

Comment: Indeed, the problem is with Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docker file if the image here https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/41bd7bf3f487e6dc0036fd73efaff6ccb6fbbacd/14/bullseye/Dockerfile you'll see that they create a user with id 999.
I guess your local data directory is owned by you, which is in most cases user 1000.
So if you chown the data directory to user 999, it should work.

Comment: No, i did ```sudo chown 999 /media/secret/DATOS/servicios-basesdatos/data/```and I had the same error: ```FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership```

Comment: that is strange. I just tried it with a new and empty data folder, with no chown at all. Container was build without any problem, and afterwards the data folder was owned by user 999, so I even did not have to chown it myself... Are there files in the data folder that for some reason are write protected?

Comment: No, data is created by postgres. And its empty

Answer (score -1):

Think this line is crucial here

```
servicios-basesdatos-db-1  | 2023-01-31 09:07:54.976 UTC [83] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
```

You may try this solution (initialization of volume in volumes) like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
     image: postgres:14.6
     volumes:
        - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres:
```

Comment: My idea is that it should be in a folder locally, not on a volume. And with this lines, we create a volume.

Comment: You can't really do anything with the opaque binary format the database stores its files in, so a named volume could be a good match here.  It can also be substantially faster on some platforms.

Comment: Ok and if you try to remove your local folder before starting docker like: sudo rm -fr data ? It may see existing folder when you starting up container and has no write permission to it.